# Problema em ler os caracteres da string(logica) - C

Tags: c, lógica

Estava fazendo um programa par cadastrar alunos, professores e matérias em structs diferentes. Porem tenho que vincula-los. Pra isso fiz uma função so pra fazer essa tarefa, porem não consigo resolver um erro de lógica dentro.

Segue a linha de codigo que se encontra o erro

```
strcpy(aluno[alunos[loop2] - 1].materia[aluno[loop2].cont_mate], disc[disciplinas[loop] - 1].nome_disciplina);
                    strcpy(disc[disciplinas[loop2] - 1].turma_1[disc[loop2].cont_1], aluno[alunos[loop] - 1].nome_aluno);
                    aluno[loop2].cont_mate++;
                    disc[loop2].cont_1++;
```

> Exception thrown at 0x0F9CE5A7 (ucrtbased.dll) in Project5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0118DC4C.

Função matricula aluno(vinculo):

```
int matricula_aluno(int qntd_aluno, int qntd_disc, Aluno aluno[], Disciplina disc[])
{
    int loop, loop2, qntd_matriculas, qntd_disciplinas;
    int alunos[20], disciplinas[20], turma[20];

    //deixar todas as posicoes do vetor = 100 para comparacao com o vetor original
    for (loop = 0; loop < 20; loop++)
    {
        alunos[loop] = 100;
        disciplinas[loop] = 100;
    }

    system("cls");

    printf("Alunos Cadastrados\n\n");
    for (loop = 0; loop < qntd_aluno; loop++)
    {
        //print de todos os nomes de alunos
        printf("%i. %s\n", (loop + 1), aluno[loop].nome_aluno);
    }

    printf("\nQuantos alunos deseja matricular?\n");
    scanf("%i", &qntd_matriculas);

    //for de alunos
    for (loop = 1; loop < qntd_matriculas + 1; loop++)
    {
        printf("\nDigite o numero do aluno:\n");
        scanf("%i", &alunos[loop - 1]);
    }

    system("cls");

    //____________________________________________________________

    printf("Disciplinas Cadastradas\n\n");
    for (loop = 0; loop < qntd_disc; loop++)
    {
        //print de todas as disciplinas
        printf("%i. %s\n", (loop + 1), disc[loop].nome_disciplina);
    }

    printf("\nQuantas disciplinas deseja matricular?\n");
    scanf("%i", &qntd_disciplinas);

    //for de disciplinas
    for (loop = 0; loop < qntd_disciplinas; loop++)
    {
        printf("\nDigite o numero da disciplina:\n");
        scanf("%i", &disciplinas[loop]);
    }

    for (loop = 0; loop < qntd_disciplinas; loop++)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Qual turma deseja para a materia de %s.\n", disc[disciplinas[loop] - 1].nome_disciplina);
        printf("1 - Turma 1\n");
        printf("2 - Turma 2\n\n");
        printf("Turma: ");
        scanf("%i", &turma[loop]);
    }

    for (loop = 0; loop < 5; loop++)
    {
        for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < 5; loop2++)
        {
            if (disciplinas[loop] != 100 && alunos[loop2] != 100)
            {
                //condicao de aplicacao na turma 1 ou na turma 2

                if (turma[loop] == 1)
                {
                    if (loop2 < aluno[loop2].cont_mate)
                    {
                        strcpy(aluno[alunos[loop2] - 1].materia[aluno[loop2].cont_mate], disc[disciplinas[loop] - 1].nome_disciplina);
                        strcpy(disc[disciplinas[loop2] - 1].turma_1[disc[loop2].cont_1], aluno[alunos[loop] - 1].nome_aluno);
                        aluno[loop2].cont_mate++;
                        disc[loop2].cont_1++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strcpy(aluno[alunos[loop2] - 1].materia[loop], disc[disciplinas[loop] - 1].nome_disciplina);
                        strcpy(disc[disciplinas[loop2] - 1].turma_1[disc[loop2].cont_1], aluno[alunos[loop] - 1].nome_aluno);
                        //copia para a struct o nome das materias que nao tem ´100´ no vetor
                        aluno[loop2].cont_mate++;
                        disc[loop2].cont_1++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (loop2 < aluno[loop2].cont_mate)
                    {
                        strcpy(aluno[alunos[loop2] - 1].materia[aluno[loop2].cont_mate], disc[disciplinas[loop] - 1].nome_disciplina);
                        strcpy(disc[disciplinas[loop2] - 1].turma_2[disc[loop2].cont_2], aluno[alunos[loop] - 1].nome_aluno);
                        aluno[loop2].cont_mate++;
                        disc[loop2].cont_2++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strcpy(aluno[alunos[loop2] - 1].materia[loop], disc[disciplinas[loop] - 1].nome_disciplina);
                        strcpy(disc[disciplinas[loop2] - 1].turma_2[disc[loop2].cont_2], aluno[alunos[loop] - 1].nome_aluno);
                        //copia para a struct o nome das materias que nao tem ´100´ no vetor
                        aluno[loop2].cont_mate++;
                        disc[loop2].cont_2++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como foram definidas as estruturas `Aluno` e `Disciplina` ?  O que quer dizer com erro de lógica ? Dá um erro a compilar ? Não faz o que você pretende ? Dá só erro a executar ?

Comment: O erro que você está vendo provavelmente está relacionado com uma string não inicializada (sem o `\0`). Isso pode fazer com que o `strcpy` tente escrever em uma área de memória não alocada para o programa, o que resulta no erro que você está vendo. Só não (quero) consigo confirmar porque está realmente difícil entender o que o seu código está fazendo. Você deveria usar mais variáveis e funções para melhorar a legibilidade do código.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?